# rsync to/from a remote directory that has spaces in name

Tags: bash, shell, rsync

I need to enter different directories to copy some files using `rsync`, but those directories have names with spaces (for example, "CODE ONE"). So when `rsync` is running, I can't enter those directories. The name of directories is in a config file, and in the bash script the name is in a variable.

This is the code:

```
cat listdirectories.txt | while read line
do
        DIRNAME=$(echo $line | awk -F\| '{print $1}')

rsync -rqut SERVER:/${DIRNAME}/${NAME_FILE} DIR_TARGET/

done
```

I try put double quote, but the result is the same.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where did you put the double quotes?

Comment: BTW, it would be helpful if you specified your input format (ie. pipe-delimited contents) explicitly, rather than requiring the reader to interpret from your code.

Comment: Also note that pipe characters are allowed in filenames on UNIX (as are newlines!), so there are plenty of possible file / directory names that the file format in use here can't possibly process.

Comment: BTW, next time, consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing everything it finds before asking questions here.

Comment: I put the double quotes in variable: /"${DIRNAME}"/

Comment: @user3658319, ...and didn't also put them in `echo $line`? You need them there too -- compare `echo hello * world` and `echo "hello * world"` for an egregious example, but there are plenty of subtler places where it matters as well. (Look at what happens if you have a name with two spaces next to each other rather than one, or a name with a tab character literal, or a space at the beginning or end of the name).

Comment: @user3658319, ...that said, `echo` isn't well-suited to represent arbitrary content literally *in general* -- see the POSIX standard specifying the command's usage at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html, and you'll note that output is *entirely unspecified* if content contains any backslash literals or starts with `-n`, and that the specification allows wildly different behaviors depending on whether XSI extensions are present. Thus, while using `echo "$foo"` is better than `echo $foo`, using `printf '%s\n' "$foo"` is still further improvement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while IFS='|' read -r dirname _; do
    printf -v dirname_q '%q' "$dirname"
    rsync -rqut "SERVER:/${dirname_q}/${filename}" target_dir/
done <listofdirectories.txt
```

Now, let's talk about the details:

- `IFS='|' read -r dirname _` -- configures `read` to split into multiple variables on `|` characters, putting the first column's contents into `dirname` and the rest into a variable named `_` (which, by convention, is understood to be an unimportant / throwaway variable). See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for details.
- `read -r` -- Using the `-r` argument to `read` prevents backslash literals within filenames from being stripped.
- `printf -v dirname_q '%q' "$dirname"` -- puts a shell-quoted version of the contents of `"$dirname"` into the variable `dirname_q`, ensuring that if interpreted by the same shell on the remote side, the contents will evaluate back to the original string.
- `<listofdirectories.txt` -- redirection from a file is much more efficient than piping from a process (such as `cat`), and avoids running the loop in a subshell, which would create bugs as described in [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Finally, note the use of lower-case variable names.  [IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 specifies that all-uppercase environment variables are reserved for system use, and variables containing lowercase characters are reserved for applications.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html) Since shell variables and environment variables share a single namespace, this means that your shell programs should use all-lowercase names for their own variables (as opposed to when interacting with or retrieving shell variables such as `PWD` or `PS1`, or system-impacting variables such as `LANG`, `LC_ALL`, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to quote it both for you shell *and* for the remote system

```
rsync -rqut "SERVER:/'$DIRNAME'/'$NAME_FILE'" DIR_TARGET/
# local ....^...............................^
# remote ............^........^.^..........^
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not actually necessary. `rsync ./hello\ world.txt 'hostname:hello world.txt'` just worked for me.

Comment: Oooh. Source has different rules. Good call; incorporating into my own answer with some tweaks (which, admittedly, assume a `/bin/sh` provided by bash for filenames with particularly interesting nonprintable characters)...